# C# Fill ComboBox1 from dataGridView1

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace ArsCRM
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=test\s08r2;Initial Catalog=Demo;User id=sa;Password=123456";
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"
            SELECT acSubject, acAddress, acPost, acName, acPhone, 
            acFieldSA, acFieldSB, acFieldSC, acFieldSD, acFieldSE, 
            anFieldNA, anFieldNB, anFieldNC, anFieldND, anFieldNE, OdgovornaOsoba, acSubjTypeBuyer
            FROM ARS.dbo._ARSCRM_vSubjekti order by acSubject
            ", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;


        }


    private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearch.Text))
        {
            (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("acSubject like '%{0}%'", txtSearch.Text);
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;

        if (dgv.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
            txtAcFieldSA.Text = dgv.Rows[dgv.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString();            
    }

}
}
```

I have this code which on the last two line fill up txtAcFieldSA with 6. column from selected row.

I want some thing on ComboBox1. When I select some row that in ComboBox1 fill 6. column. Is that possible?

Comment: the question is not understandable, could you please rewrite the question?

Comment: please re-write the question, as it doesn't make sense

Comment: Romano has solved this. I need that ComboBox1 fill with 6. columns from selected row in dataGridView1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joust do it according to the TextBox

```
    private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {


                DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;

                if (dgv.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
                 {
                    txtAcFieldSA.Text = dgv.Rows[dgv.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                    ComboBox1.Text = dgv.Rows[dgv.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
                 }
            }
```

or if you want to add it as item to the comboBox:

```
    private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;

            if (dgv.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
            {
                txtAcFieldSA.Text = dgv.Rows[dgv.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString();

                ComboBox1.Items.Add(dgv.Rows[dgv.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex].Cells[6].Value.ToString();)
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you expect will happen with this code if there are no selected cells? Also please reformat it so people can actually read it

Comment: How is any of this different from a 1:1 copy of the last function from question code?

Comment: You are right. I forgot the brackets. But why do you give me commands. You can reformat the code by yourself. Thank you!

Comment: There is code to add cell contents to the ComboBox. Thats the difference ;-)

Comment: Thank you Romano, that's what I need. Simple as that.Next step for me it's connect this ComboBox1 to another data.

Comment: @RomanoZumbé woah, sneaky bastard :) hiding the change so far to the right.